# Compile Unix with a custom application

Tags: compiling, application

I wonder, is it possible to compile Unix along with a my custom program so that it runs only my custom program on start up of computer, as if my program starting with boot up?

Comment: You mean a daemon?

Comment: I'm sure you can do that in linux, but you may need to do some research, hot to compile linux distribution and program you want.

Comment: Yes, this is called a kiosk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you only want users to be able to run one program, you can replace the user's shell with the absolute path to the program in the passwd file - assuming a local passwd file..

Answer (score 0):

As you say, directly no. The Unix kernel is separate from the userland programs, and is built separately.

But what you want to do is possible. The `init` program, traditionally the first process to run on Unix, is a (somewhat special) normal user process. So it is certainly possible to set things up so that your program is the only one running on the system. But consider that `init` traditionally has a lot of other responsibilities (check configuration and set up userland to run, check filesystems if required, ...), so I'd advise against it. The `init` (and other) machinery required by a modern Unix system is lightweight, and it is much easier to set a "normal" system up o just start your application normally after handling the chores of starting up.